# Custom Option type file data not showing in Sales/Order Admin

Tags: magento-1.9, product, custom-options, sales-order, file-upload

I created a simple product with custom option type file like this :

[image]

when i try to order this product at front end, there is input type file and i insert the file and click add to cart button, and last step i did checkout and there's no problem at all in those steps, but when i see the sales/order for this product i don't see the custom option with the file that i already chose before

[image]

after i inspect it further,when adding the product to the cart using ajax, is not sending the custom option value :

[image]